# Calculating 2d position of 3d point cloud data represented by angles and lengths

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, 3d, geometry

I'm trying to build a thing that renders point cloud data stored in a specific way to a canvas using Javascript.

The data is stored as (JSON, where -> represents a range of values including the two extremes)

{"xangle":-Math.PI*2 -> Math.PI*2,"yangle": -Math.PI*2 -> Math.PI*2,"disntancefromorigin":10,"colour":blue}

I've been having some trouble working out what the maths should be for turning the xangle, which represents the angle away from the x axis the line is and the yangle, which is the same but from the yaxis, and the distance from the origin into a "3d" point.

I've been running code which generates a large array of points the same distance from the origin with the same distance and trying to manually brute force the algorithm till i got it right - but that didn't help much.

[image: here's an image which might make it clearer]

thanks for any help, if I've not made something clear or you want to see the code just ask.

EDIT: I should add, I'm just going for an Orthographic representation (at least till I can get that working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = distancefromorigin
y=r*cos(yAngle)
x=r*cos(xAngle)
z=+-r*sqrt( 1-cos^2(yAngle) - cos^2(xAngle) )
```

Edit: Last equation is from `x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2`

You cannot say if you have to pick + or - because your problem is ill defined!

Comment: thanks, I've implemented this as:   `function sqr(x){
 return x*x;
}

function angleToPoints(point,offset){  
 var x = Math.cos(point.ya+offset)*point.dis;  
 var y = Math.cos(point.xa)*point.dis;  
 var z = point.dis*Math.sqrt(1-sqr(Math.cos(point.ya)) - sqr(Math.cos(point.xa)));  
 return pointConstuctor(x,y,z);  
}`   but for some reason z often returns Not a Number...  _0.15000000000000002 0.5 NaN  
0.3167581064644854 2.1357083341732217 NaN  
0.4405915095812384 2.459187675357626 NaN_   where the first number is xangle, second yangle and third z value returned.  (apologies for formatting)

Comment: You have to use ya for y and xa for x, not the other way round. But that's not the problem. The argument of sqrt seems to become negative sometimes. This indicates that the two angles are not the ones you describe in your problem, ie. ax from the point to the x-axis, and ay from to point to the y-axis.

Comment: oops, yeah. I think I was thinking of it more in a way where the y-plane would be defined by the x-angle.